# Binding VuexFire to a collection filtered with a query

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex, vuexfire

I'm unsuccessfully trying to bind a Vuex state attribute to a queried collection in FireStore. I was wondering if anyone with more experience could point me in the right direction. This is what I'm currently doing:

In a Vuex Module called auth I'm declaring the following bind to userArticles

```
export const bindUserArticles = firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }, id) => {
    return bindFirestoreRef('userArticles', userCollectionRef('articles', id))
  })
```

This in turn points to a firebase method for querying the data (which works)

```
export const userCollectionRef = (collectionName, id) => {
  return firestore().collection(collectionName).where("author.idAuthor", "==", id)
}
```

And I'm importing and dispatching the method in my Vue file in the following way

```
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters('user', ['currentUser']),
},
      methods: {
        ...mapActions('articles', ['bindUserArticles']),
    },
     watch: {
        currentUser () {
          this.bindUserArticles(this.currentUser.id)
        }
      }
```

So when the currentUser is updated upon login the method is triggered. The method is triggered and the right id is being sent, I've tested it with console.log. There is no error being displayed. When I try for example to modify the idAuthor of an existing article in the database, the list userArticles does not update. When I try adding or deleting an article from the database that has the specific idAuthor, the list userArticles does not update. I've also tried placing the ***this.bindUserArticles(this.currentUser.id)*** in the created() and mounted() life-cycle, to no avail.Does anyone have a clue where I'm going wrong about this?

Thanks in advance